# Called unimplemented OpenGL ES API

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I've already checked several posts on SOF, so I'm using a real device instead of the emulator, which is Galaxy Nexus(Android 4.2).
And also I set something like :

```
mGLSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
mGLSurfaceView.setRenderer(new MyRenderer(this));
```

STILL, crazy logs of "libEGL called unimplemented OpenGL ES API".

Any help? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is probably caused by an incomplete EGL or OpenGL ES 2.0 driver for Android.  You should try to find an updated driver, if available.  The other option is to change your app's code to not use setEGLContextClientVersion(2).  There is a sample in the Android SDK named hello-gl2 that works without using setEGLContextClientVersion(2).  Or, use OpenGL ES 1.1 or native code instead.  This article details this:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/porting-opengl-games-to-android-on-intel-atom-processors-part-1

Comment: I tried to test the single openGLES activity alone, and it worked.
But whenever I tried to link the openGL activity to another activity(contains a listview and set a intent to the openGl activity), the problem showed up again..\

Comment: Thanks, bumping up client version to 2.0 worked for me : )